# jQuery ASP.NET MVC 405 POST not allowed

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

After migrating from 2 version to 3 I have get on my MVC (Model–view–controller) site 405 POST not allowed
on page partial update, anybody know whats wrong?

```
Response Headersview source
Server  ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date    Mon, 21 Mar 2011 19:42:52 GMT
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
Cache-Control   private
Content-Length  0
Connection  Close
Request Headersview source
Host    localhost:38213
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13
Accept  text/html, */*
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive  115
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
Referer http://localhost:38213/ru/Price
Content-Length  95

http://localhost:38213/Price/Filter?currency=1&groupFilter=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the action you are requesting is not restricted to GET-only requests? Do you see `[HttpGet]` or `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]` on the action which is producing this error?

Comment: Yes, method has attribute [HTTPPost]

Actually, I resolve this issue. The problem is in using Telerik MVC controls.
After removing it all works fine.